# Drawing CLUT and RGB images to the same window using XPutImage

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib

I'm trying to draw two types of graphics to my window opened using `XCreateWindow()`:

1. RGB graphics taken from a memory buffer of raw 32-bit pixels
   (AARRGGBB), no alpha blending.
2. CLUT graphics taken from a memory buffer of 8-bit pixels that describe entries into a
   separate color map.

I can easily draw RGB graphics to my window by creating an `XImage` from my memory buffer using `XCreateImage()` and then I can draw this image using `XPutImage()`. This is working fine.

Things seem to get trickier, however, when it comes to drawing CLUT graphics. As far as I can see, Xlib has a special visual type named **PseudoColor** which seems to do what I want because the doc says the following:

> For **PseudoColor**, a pixel value indexes a colormap to produce
>   independent RGB values, and the RGB values can be changed dynamically

([source](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/visual-types.html#Visual))

However, as far as I can see, the visual type of the window has to be specified when creating the window since it is passed as a parameter to `XCreateWindow()`. So to me it looks as if I have to decide between having either a **TrueColor** or a **PseudoColor** window visual but I can't have both at the same time.

So is this right? In other words, is it not possible to draw both RGB and CLUT pixels to the same window?

Of course, I could work around this limitation by manually converting the CLUT pixels to RGB ones and then draw the converted pixels using `XPutImage()` as described above. However, before I do that, I'd first like to know if there's any way to draw CLUT graphics directly alongside RGB graphics.

**EDIT**

For reference, here's what I have tried so far:

```
unsigned char *pixels = malloc(640 * 480);  // in reality this is filled with real pens
unsigned int palette[256];   // in reality this is filled with real RGB values
Colormap cm;
XColor rgb;
int i;

cm = XCreateColormap(display, window, visual, AllocAll);

for(i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    rgb.pixel = i;
    rgb.red = GetRValue(palette[i]) * 257;
    rgb.green = GetGValue(palette[i]) * 257;
    rgb.blue = GetBValue(palette[i]) * 257;
    rgb.flags = DoRed|DoGreen|DoBlue;
    XStoreColor(display, cm, &rgb);
}

XSetWindowColormap(display, window, cm);

image = XCreateImage(display, visual, 8, ZPixmap, 0, pixels, 640, 480, 8, 640);
XPutImage(display, window, gc, image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 640, 480);
XFlush(display);

image->data = NULL;
XDestroyImage(image);

XFreeColormap(display, cm);
```

It fails already in `XCreateColormap()`, saying:

> X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
>   Major opcode of failed request:  78 (X_CreateColormap)   Serial number
>   of failed request:  497   Current serial number in output stream:  500

If I use `AllocNone` instead of `AllocAll`, `XCreateColormap()` succeeds but `XStoreColor()` fails, saying:

> X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied) 
>   Major opcode of failed request:  89 (X_StoreColors)
>   Serial number of failed request:  493   Current serial number in output stream:  751

Comment: What happens when you draw a PseudoColor visual onto a TrueColor window? (I'm guessing it messes up the colours, because it doesn't have a colormap, or it just returns an error)

Comment: (I meant a PseudoColor image, not visual)

Comment: @user253751: I'm not even getting as far as being able to actually draw anything. It doesn't even allow me to create a colormap, i.e. the call `XCreateColormap(display, window, visual, AllocAll)` fails and returns a `BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)` error, presumably because I'm passing `AllocAll` and according to the docs this must be `AllocNone` for `TrueColor` but obviously I need pens for what I want to do...

Comment: Okay. Then my assumption is: X can't do this.

Comment: @user253751: I think so too. So I guess I have to convert the CLUT pixels to RGB and draw them as RGB then.

Comment: FWIW I've also added some code now but I think it's impossible to do what I want.